# Does align 8 make the inc command to be by steps of 8?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

while checking the assembly of wget I saw this, which is the beginning of the packer I assume:

```
UPX1:004ED812                 align 8
UPX1:004ED818
UPX1:004ED818 loc_4ED818:                             ; CODE XREF: UPX1:loc_4ED829j
UPX1:004ED818                 mov     al, [esi]
UPX1:004ED81A                 inc     esi
UPX1:004ED81B                 mov     [edi], al
UPX1:004ED81D                 inc     edi
```

my question is: Does the `align 8` make the inc `esi` to be incremented each iteration by 8, which means one byte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INC increases by 1, otherwise hell will definitely break loose.

More specifically, I couldn't find any decent documentation for current assembly language. I did, however, find this [reference](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-c-compiler-for-windows-general-compatibility-with-other-products/#16) . According to this, the align directive just controls how the next instruction opcode is aligned in memory.

This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

INC R is exactly the same as ADD R, 1.

The align 8 instruction makes the *address of* the INC R a multiple of 8. This is an optimisation inserted by the compiler to ensure that the target of a jump or call falls at the start of a cache-line, and thus the pipeline of the processor can be more efficiently filled.

Comment: It's **not exactly** the same. `INC` always preserves the state of the `CF` flag, while `ADD` always overwrites it according to the result.